# Delayed NUnit Assert message evaluation

Tags: c#, nunit

I have this assert in my test code

```
Assert.That(() => eventData.Count == 0,
Is.True.After(notificationPollingDelay),
"Received unexpected event with last event data" + eventData.Last().Description());
```

that asserts some condition after a period of time and on failure produces a message. it fails to run because the message string is constructed when the assert starts and not when the assert ends. therefore the `eventData` collection is still empty (as it is initially) and the attempt to get the `Description` of the last item in the collection fails. is there a workaround or decent alternative to this in `NUnit` or do I have to revert to using `Thread.Sleep` in my tests?

PS: I'm using NUnit 2.5.10.

Comment: As far as I know that is no native NUnit assert syntax. Which assertion library are you using?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - That is valid NUnit assert syntax when using the constraint based model. `After` is a delayed constraint http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=delayedConstraint&r=2.6.2

Comment: @manojlds: Thanks for the info. For anyone interested: [DelayedConstraint](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=delayedConstraint&r=2.5.10) in combination with [EqualConstraint](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalConstraint&r=2.5.10) using the [constrained-based assert module](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.5.10).

Comment: I think you are out of luck. According to the documentation I linked to in my last comment there is no overload that accepts a delegate to create the message at a later point in time.

Comment: <Luke's Voice>Nnnnoooooooooooooooo</Luke's Voice>

Comment: @mtijn: wouldn't you like to suggest to NUnit team to add ability to pass lambdas as assertion messages generators? :)

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk yes but I think the problem is more fundamental in that NUnit currently doesn't support a clear enough practical distinction between assert start and assert end states

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use this scheme:

```
var constrain = Is.True.After(notificationPollingDelay);
var condition = constrain.Matches(() => eventData.Count == 0);
Assert.IsTrue(condition, 
              "Received unexpected event with last event data" + 
              eventData.Last().Description());
```

This method is similar to the use Thread.Sleep

Comment: I like how you pulled apart the code into these logical steps. I have no compiler handy to check the results right now, is the second line (establishing the condition) where the wait occurs?? If so I guess this is the best workaround so far..

Comment: Pending occurs during in `var condition = constrain.Matches(() => eventData.Count == 0);`. Checked with the compiler when I writing this code :)

Answer (score 4):

In NUnit version 3.50 I had to use a different syntax.
Here is the example:

```
var delayedConstraint = Is.True.After( delayInMilliseconds: 100000, pollingInterval: 100);
Assert.That( () => yourCondition, delayedConstraint );
```

This will test whether `yourCondition` is true waiting a certain maximum time using the `DelayedConstraint` created by the `Is.True.After` method.

In this example the `DelayedConstraint` is configured to use maximum time of 100 seconds polling every 0.1 seconds.

See aslo the legacy NUnit 2.5 documentation for [DelayedConstraint](https://nunit.org/index.php?p=delayedConstraint&r=2.5).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is "don't include that text in your failure message".  I personally almost never include a failure message; if your test is atomic enough you don't need to do it.  Usually if I need to figure out a cryptic failure, only a debugger helps anyway.

If you really want to do it, this code should work without managing the threads yourself.

```
try
{
    Assert.That(() => eventData.Count == 0, Is.True.After(notificationPollingDelay));
}
catch(AssertionException)
{
    throw new Exception("Received unexpected event with last event data" + eventData.Last().Description());
}
```

Comment: `don't include that text in your failure message` - you give one advice and break one of the most important things in a test - try catch. Especially an assertion. -1