# Unit Test async eventhandler

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    //DO Something
    async_eventhandler += the_eventhandler(async_eventhandler);
}

private void async_eventhandler
{
test = test2
    // test2 comes from client, after here TestMethod have to start
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("test_test", test);
}
```

The Unit Test failed, because the methods are async.
String `test` is "NULL" because the value `test2` comes later. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. Before `Assert.AreEqual` you may insert `Thread.Sleep(MaxTimeoutForEvent)`
2. Use delayed assert. An example can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319435/delayed-nunit-assert-message-evaluation/27081445)

P.S. Remember about `TestCleanup` :)

Comment: 1.)    Thread.Sleep -> Is does not work.
2.)    I cannot interpreted the code, how i use it in my example

Comment: Are you sure that `async_eventhandler` is Invoked after TestMethod start?

Comment: 2. With NUnit: Assert.That("test_test", Is.EqualTo(test).After(3000)); is also not working. TestInit and Testmethod starts sync. testmethod have to wait to testinit, but they dont

Comment: `[TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("2");
            NUnit.Framework.Assert.That("test_test", Is.EqualTo(test).After(3000));
        }` //if i use MessageBox.Show("2"), and wait for click the message box, until the event async_eventhandler is ending, then t get the right string test an the the test is passed :) but i dont wont use message.box :)

Comment: I have still not a correct answer. The Testmethod have to wait for a notification event. But how i Do it?